# Getting UTF8 charset instead of ASCII in java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am creating text file in ASCII Charset format.When read it again,its
    giving UTF8 Charset.Why does its giving UTF8 Charset instead of ASCII?

```
   public static void fileStreamWriter() throws IOException {
   Charset cs = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
   System.setProperty("file.encoding", "US-ASCII");
   String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
   String stCr = new String(text.getBytes());
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new 
   FileOutputStream("C:/upload/FItest"), cs);
    try {
        writer.write(stCr);
        writer.flush();
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
    }

     public static void readEncodingCharset(String path) throws IOException    

    {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "US-ASCII");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    String s;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("C:/upload/FItest");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        s = isr.getEncoding(); 
        System.out.println("Charset Encoding type : "+s);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {            
            fis.close();            
            isr.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Slightly confused...why is the path for your `FileOutputStream` "C:/upload/FItest" but for your `FileInputStream` it's "C:/amex/upload/FItest" ?

Comment: Also confused:  If you create a file in ASCII encoding, then it should contain only ASCII characters (i.e., characters with code points in the range [0x00..0x7F]), but the UTF-8 encoding of any string consisting entirely of characters in that range is indistinguishable from the ASCII encoding of the same string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `System.setProperty` lines, they're useless and don't do what you think.

Since you didn't specify the encoding in the `InputStreamReader` constructor, the platform default is used, which in your case seems to be `UTF-8`. Add `"US-ASCII"` as a parameter to `InputStreamReader`.

`InputStreamReader` does **not** guess the encoding. It uses the platform default unless you specify differently, and you should always explicitly specify the encoding to make sure that the program works the same on different platforms.